# Is there a way to be the 'creator' of an iron golem when you summon it with a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When you create an iron golem manually (4 iron blocks with a pumpkin on top), it automatically labels you as its creator, and will not attack when you hit it. However, using the `/summon iron_golem` command does no such thing. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the Minecraft Wiki, specifically, the Iron Golem's Data Values:
[image: Minecraft Wiki Data Values]
These are the NBT tags being held by the Iron Golem. It looks like the Iron Golem has its own tag that shows whether it was created by a player.

When creating an Iron Golem manually, this tag is set to `1` (true). But the `/summon` command does no such thing *by default*.

But there is a way! Although `/summon` does not set NBT tags *by default*, you can tell it to by specifying the tags **after** the summon position.

Try this command:

```
/summon minecraft:iron_golem ~ ~ ~ {PlayerCreated:1b}
```

This command summons an Iron Golem with the `PlayerCreated` tag set to `1b`.

Learn more about these concepts on the Minecraft Wiki:

- [Iron Golem](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem)
- [NBT Format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format)
- [The `/summon` Command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/summon)

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for! I was not sure what the argument was, and I was unable to find official documentation for Minecraft commands. Very helpful, thank you.